# Adding thumbnails and remove button to a form file input

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, file-upload, thumbnails

I am using Rails and I've got a form with a bunch of fields and one of those is image uploading. For now it's just a typical button with multiple option on and it does almost everything I need, but I'd like images' previews (thumbnails) to appear when a user selects images and I'd like to have a "remove" button on these thumbnails in case user decides to remove some image from the collection.

I've tried to use `dropzone.js` but I dont wanna send form as JSON and I want files to be a part of file input field.
Also I tried to use `Jquery File Upload`, but I got too confused in all that and so I've tried to use just `FileReader API` which is what I needed, but I couldnt manage to add remove buttons... Also I wouldnt like to use ajax for that, I think it can be done without it somehow and I dont necesserily need a drag and drop functionality.

Anyway, I think it should be an easy thing to do but I cant find any appropriate tutorials or something for that, so I hope to get some link to a tutorial or just some hint that'll help me to solve the issue.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use canvas and FileReader API. Something like this:

```
$('#yourFileInputField').bind('change', function(e) {
  var reader;
  reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function(event) {
    var img;
    img = new Image();
    img.onload = function() {
      var canvas, context;
      canvas = $('#canvasId')[0];
      context = canvas.getContext('2d');
      context.drawImage(img, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    };
  };
  reader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0]);
});
```

When you click on remove just clear canvas and file input field.

Comment: I see, but if user chose like 5 images and then clicked on the remove button on one image, how do I remove only this image from the file input and leave the rest 4?

Comment: are your inputs created dynamically? You can wrap your input and canvas with <div>, add input's onchange event to some function (let it call imageSelected). imageSelected's body looks like my code above (just handler). 'e' param it's input, so we can access to canvas via parent div.

Comment: and remove button include to this wrapper div. In this case you can access to canvas and input. Just attach onclick event to something like this (with jQuery) function removeButtonClicked () { $(this).parent().children('input') or canvas } to clear them.